# Shader fails to compile without error message (Haskell OpenGL bindings)

Tags: haskell, opengl, glsl

I am trying to draw a sphere using the Haskell GLUT and OpenGL bindings (essentially a direct translation of the normal OpenGL types and functions). I followed [an example](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/blob/master/examples/Misc/ColorTriangle/ColorTriangle.hs) written by Sven Panne (the author of the OpenGL bindings) when writing the code, and since his [shader loading code](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/blob/master/examples/RedBook8/common/LoadShaders.hs) supported error logging, I just decided to copy it over to my project. However, when I try to compile my vertex shader, compilation  fails with the message "user error (compile log: )" and no actual compile log.

I tried running Sven Panne's triangle example on its own to make sure that there was no problem with the library or with my version of OpenGL, and it worked flawlessly. I have copy-pasted other people's shaders and tried to compile them with little success. I have made sure that the program is able to actually open the shader file and read the source code, by printing it to console.

My vertex shader looks like so:

```c
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
   color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

and if anyone is curious, my fragment shader looks like:

```c
#version 430 core

in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
   fColor = color;
}
```

and if anyone is interested to see the rest of my code, it is uploaded on [Github](https://github.com/SonnyJansson/EEStuff/blob/master/src/Main.hs) (sorry about the mess, but I have been trying to debug this for some time now).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. I tried to compile the shaders and make the program before I had actually done some other initialisation, which is what caused the error. I am now compiling the shaders and linking the program after setting up the window and specifying various OpenGL options.